# Removing repeated characters from a string in scheme

Tags: string, recursion, scheme

I've been trying this question for a long time but am not getting very far with it. The question is asking to produce a string where all the repeated characters from the inputed string are replaced by a single instance of the character.

For example,

```
(remove-repeats "aaaab") => "ab"
(remove-repeats "caaabb aa") => "cab a"
```

Since I 'm trying to do this using accumulative recursion, so far I have:

```
(define (remove-repeats s) 
  (local
    [(define (remove-repeats-acc s1 removed-so-far)
      (cond
        [(empty? (string->list s1))""]
        [else 
         (cond
           [(equal? (first (string->list s1)) (second (string->list s1))) 
         (list->string (remove-repeats-acc (remove (second (string->list s1)) (string->list s1)) (add1 removed-so-far)))]
           [else (list->string (remove-repeats-acc (rest (string->list s1)) removed-so-far))])]))]
    (remove-repeats-acc s 0)))
```

But this doesn't seem to be right. Please help me modify this to work.

Thank You!!

Comment: Please put your code in code blocks, properly indented os it's easier to read.

Comment: You can make code look pretty by adding at least four spaces before each line as well as starting new lines where appropriated.

Answer (score 4):

Strings are a bit annoying to work with, so we wrap it around a worker function that deals with lists instead. This way we can avoid messing around with conversions everywhere.

```
(define (remove-repeats str)
  (list->string (remove-repeats/list (string->list str))))
```

Now we can define the remove-repeats/list function using a straightforward recursion:

```
(define (remove-repeats/list xs)
  (cond
    [(empty? xs) xs]
    [(empty? (cdr xs)) xs]
    [(equal? (car xs) (cadr xs)) (remove-repeats/list (cdr xs))]
    [else (cons (car xs) (remove-repeats/list (cdr xs)))]))
```

This isn't tail-recursive, but now it should be easier to add accumulator:

```
(define (remove-repeats str)
  (list->string (remove-repeats/list-acc (string->list str) '())))

(define (remove-repeats/list-acc xs acc)
  (cond
    [(empty? xs) (reverse acc)]
    [(empty? (cdr xs)) (reverse (cons (car xs) acc))]
    [(equal? (car xs) (cadr xs)) (remove-repeats/list-acc (cdr xs) acc)]
    [else (remove-repeats/list-acc (cdr xs) (cons (car xs) acc))]))
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a version I'm fond of, in [Typed Racket](http://doc.racket-lang.org/ts-guide/):

```
#lang typed/racket
(: remove-repeats : String -> String)
(define (remove-repeats s)
  (define-values (chars last)
    (for/fold: ([chars : (Listof Char) null] [last : (Option Char) #f])
      ([c (in-string s)] #:when (not (eqv? last c)))
      (values (cons c chars) c)))
  (list->string (reverse chars)))
```